# filter dates fields from paradox db using microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0

Tags: c#, paradox

Hi I'm trying to filter data fields from a paradox database table (from information system on programmed on delphi)...

I successfully made the connection with the connection string:

```
Provider =Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =c:\bddir; Extended Properties =Paradox 5.x;
```

I can even successfully execute queries like `select * from mytable`

But when I'm trying to do queries like:

`SELECT  *  FROM  entries WHERE date = '2011-1-1'`  thru a `c#` application with the cxstr

above.. and it said: `Data type mismatch in criteria expression`

any solutions?? I tried things like `StrToDate` or `QuotedStr` and it didn't work...

:(

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM entries WHERE date = #1/1/11#
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM entries WHERE date = '2011-1-1'
```

look here: [MS-TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966377.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it it's:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table 
WHERE 
  year(dateField) >= 2011 AND 
  month(dateField) >= 1 AND 
  day(dateField) >= 1
```

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: 10/10 can confirm this answered my question about Microsoft Access and selecting by date too.